# How do I fix my link in modal class on Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-5

I have a template to show posts and each post has post.id.

Also there is a button to open modal and "yes" button must delete post with post.id that I clicked.

But when I do this it deleting the first post on current page instead of the right one I clicked before.

```
...

<div class="col-md-9">

    {% for post in page %}
                <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text p-2">
                                <a class="link text-dark" href="/profile/{{post.author.username}}/"><strong class="d-block text-dark">@{{profile_user.username}}</strong>
                                </a>
                                {{post.text}}
                                {% load thumbnail %}
                                {% thumbnail post.image "960x339" crop="center" upscale=True as im %}
                                    <img class="card-img" src="{{ im.url }}">
                                {% endthumbnail %}
                        </p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="/profile/{{profile_user.username}}/{{post.id}}/" role="button">
                                          ... </a>
                                        {% if user.username == profile_user.username %}
                                            <a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="/profile/{{profile_user.username}}/{{post.id}}/edit" role="button">...</a>

                                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-muted" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                                         ...
                                        </button>

                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete post?</h1>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-muted" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">...</button>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                                                <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/profile/{{profile_user.username}}/{{post.id}}/delete">YES</a> <!-- TODO Fix id problem-->
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <small class="text-muted">{{post.pub_date}}</small>
                        </div>
                </div>
    {% endfor %}
...
```

I think the view work fine because I already tried to do this without modal and it worked fine. Is this even possible to get the right id using link in modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try attach each modal instance with specific id based on post like this:
here is an example, you should replace job.pk by post.id

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationDialog{{ job.pk }}"
     aria-hidden="true" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="confirmationDialogLabel{{ job.pk }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmationDialogLabel{{ job.pk }}">
                    Confirmation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete-job' job.pk %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this
                        job: {{ job }}</p>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="button-groups">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```